# In MS Access accdb VBA, how do I know in what order to suppy parameters for a query built on queries that require parameters

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba

In my VBA subroutine I want to create a new table from a complex query

(qryA UNION ALL qryB UNION ALL qryC)

```
strSQL = "select * into tblNew from qryComplex"
```

The subsequent queries (more than the 3 initial) require parameters (assume 4) that are found in a form that is open.

By working through choices, it works for example,

```
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
qdf.Parameters(0) = Forms!frmMain.txtF1
qdf.Parameters(1) = Forms!frmMain.txtF2
qdf.Parameters(2) = Forms!frmMain.txtF3
qdf.Parameters(3) = Forms!frmMain.txtF1
qdf.Execute
```

How do I know the required order is deterministic?

How can I determine the order and content without having to dig into the subsequent queries and try combinations?

Comment: You could use VBA to examine the query and show you the parameter order.  `For Each prm in qdf.Parameters` ... `Debug.Print prm.Name` ... `Next`

Comment: Thanks! This works and I do not have to know the order: For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm

Answer (score 1):

Access supports a `PARAMETERS` clause which lets you determine the order of parameters even if some/all of the parameters are only used in the underlying queries. You just have to ensure that you name all of the parameters and that you use the correct names and types. The `PARAMETERS` clause must be followed by a semi-colon.

You can use the Parameters Dialog in Access to help you:

[image]

[image]

Assuming all of your parameters need to be Short Text, your query would look like this:

```
PARAMETERS Param1 Text ( 255 ),Param2 Text ( 255 ), Param3 Text ( 255 );
SELECT * INTO tblNew
  FROM qryComplex;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use parameters from VBA and order in which they are placed was never an issue. You just have to state them all, from all queries involved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter names rather than their index numbers

```
qdf.Parameters("parameter example name 1") = Forms!frmMain.txtF1
qdf.Parameters("parameter example name 2") = Forms!frmMain.txtF2
qdf.Parameters("parameter example name 3") = Forms!frmMain.txtF3
qdf.Parameters("parameter example name 4") = Forms!frmMain.txtF1
```